# For loop guessing game in C

Tags: c

a program to get the user to guess the number that the program has picked as the lucky number. It uses one for loop and plenty of if statements. The problem is that my code stops after 2 tries, but suppose to give user 3 tries. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int iSecret, iGuess;
    srand(time(NULL));
    iSecret = rand() % 20 + 1;
    int tries = 0;

    printf("\nWelcome to the number guessing game!\nFor each game, you have at most 3 chances to guess a secret number from 1 to 20.\n");

    for (tries = 0; tries < 3 || iSecret == iGuess; tries++)
    {
        printf("Please, enter a number between 1 and 20!   ");
        scanf("%d", &iGuess);

        if (iGuess == iSecret)
        {
            printf("\nCongratulations! You won!");
            return 0;
        }

        else if (iGuess > iSecret)
        {
            tries++;
            printf("\nYour guess was too high.\n");
        }

        else if (iGuess < iSecret)
        {
            tries++;
            printf("\nYour guess was too low.\n");
        }
        if (tries == 3)
            break;
    }

    printf("\nYou have reached your third trials. The correct number is %d.\n",
            iSecret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tries < 3 || iSecret == iGuess;` the second statement is totally unnecessary; you are already checking that inside the loop.

Comment: `iGuess` is used before it is initialized - this is C, not yer new fangled Java and C# with their sensible initializations and what not...

Comment: why downvote? this is a beginners question with a compilable example and a well phrased question

Comment: @xmoex i agree .. people here have gotten into a habit of downvoting everything.

Answer (score 3):

You are incrementing `tries` twice: once in the `for` definition, and also later in the body of the loop.

Remove the extra `tries++` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You increment tries inside the code, as well as in the for statement.  Strip out the tries++ statements in the if-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the variable `tries` multiple times during loop execution,
once every turn and everytime you didn't guess your secret right

Answer (score 0):

1. for loop already increments tries .. you don't need to do tries++ inside if statements
2. you don't need the || condition in for loop as you are already doing the check in if statements

here is the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  int iSecret, iGuess;
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  iSecret = rand() % 20 + 1;
  int tries = 0;

  printf("\nWelcome to the number guessing game!\nFor each game, you have at most 3 chances to guess a secret number from 1 to 20.\n");


  for (tries = 0; tries < 3 ; tries++) {

      printf ("Please, enter a number between 1 and 20!   ");
      scanf ("%d", &iGuess);

      if(iGuess == iSecret){
      printf ("\nCongratulations! You won!");
      return 0;
      }

        else if (iGuess > iSecret){
        printf ("\nYour guess was too high.\n");
        }

        else if (iGuess < iSecret){
            printf ("\nYour guess was too low.\n");
                  }

  }
  printf ("\nYou have reached your third trials. The correct number is %d.\n", iSecret);

  return 0;
  }
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./test

Welcome to the number guessing game!
For each game, you have at most 3 chances to guess a secret number from 1 to 20.
Please, enter a number between 1 and 20!   2

Your guess was too low.
Please, enter a number between 1 and 20!   3

Your guess was too low.
Please, enter a number between 1 and 20!   4

Your guess was too low.

You have reached your third trials. The correct number is 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to incrementing tries too many times, the code is overly complicated, you can simplify the logic like

```
int main ()
{
  int iSecret, iGuess;
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  iSecret = rand() % 20 + 1;
  int tries = 0;

  printf("\nWelcome to the number guessing game!\nFor each game, you have at most 3 chances to guess a secret number from 1 to 20.\n");


  for (tries = 0; tries < 3; tries++) {
      printf ("Please, enter a number between 1 and 20!   ");
      scanf ("%d", &iGuess);

      if(iGuess == iSecret) {
        printf ("\nCongratulations! You won!");
        return 0;
      }

      printf ( "\nYour guess was too %s.\n", iGuess>iSecret?"high":"low");

  }
  printf ("\nYou have reached your third trials. The correct number is %d.\n", iSecret);
  return 0;
  }
```